# create virtual directory exec applies every agent run

Tags: powershell, puppet

I'm trying to create a virtual directory using the method below, because I'm having issues with the IIS module. It creates the virtual directory every time the agent runs, so there appears to be something wrong with my unless statement. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
class directories {
  $directories = {
    'test_dir' => 'virt_dir_path'
  }

  $directories.each |$k, $v| {
    exec { $k:
      unless   => '$test = Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site website -Name "${k}";
        if ($test -eq $false) {exit 1} else {exit 0}',
      command  => 'New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site website -Name ${k} -PhysicalPath ${v}',
      provider => powershell,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICS you have 2 issues:

- Your condition is in a single-quoted string, so I'd expect Puppet to not expand the variable `${k}`.
- `$test -eq $false` should always evaluate to `$false`, since PowerShell does some black mag^W^Wimplicit type conversions when performing comparison operations. Because of that you need to pay attention to what you're comparing with what and in which order.

  Example:

  ```
  PS C:\> 'false' -eq $false
  True
  PS C:\> $false -eq 'false'
  False
  ```

  The above example gives different results depending on the order of the operands, because the second operand is implicitly converted to match the type of the first operand. In the first case that results in `'false' -eq 'false'`, which evaluates to true, but in the second case you get `$false -eq $true` (which obviously evaluates to false), because PowerShell interprets [non-empty strings as `$true`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) in a boolean context.

Change your code to something like this:

```
$directories.each |$k, $v| {
  exec { $k:
    command  => "New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site website -Name '${k}' -PhysicalPath '${v}'",
    unless   => "if (Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site website -Name '${k}') {exit 0} else {exit 1}",
    provider => powershell,
  }
}
```

You could also make the condition

```
exit (1 - [int][bool](Get-WebVirtualDirectory -Site website -Name '${k}'))
```

if you prefer something with a little more hack-value.

Comment: I think your keyboard flipped out on that second bullet point.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Why is that?

Comment: "some black mag^W^Wimplicit"

Comment: <Ctrl>-<W> is a shortcut for "delete the previous word" in terminals. I'm using it as a stylistic device here.